# How do you find the source of specific underlying Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web, firebug

How do you find the source of specific actioning Javascript that's being activated after clicking a certain item?

For example --

A site has:

```
<ul id="list0" class="list">
  <li id="listItem0">
  <li id="listItem1">
  <li id="listItem2" class="selected">
    <a href="#">Labrador Retriever</a>
```

On the webpage, when that `listItem2` item (`<a href="#">`) is clicked, it loads specific information on the item (Labrador Retrievers) into a pane on the right (without refreshing the page or going anywhere).

How would you find the underlying Javascript that's doing this? I did a quick search with Firebug for the `"#"` link, but as expected, that's like trying to find a needle in a haystack of needles.

I just don't know how you'd even go about tracking this down. It appears that the page is also using 10-12 external Javascript files, as well, making it all the more difficult to find what in the Javascript is watching and actioning on this specific `<a href="#">`.

I thought that perhaps setting some sort of breakpoint would help to trace what in the Javascript is doing the work, but I only see three types of breakpoints -- element/child removal, or attribute change -- which don't seem applicable to what's happening here.

Answer (score 1):

I believe in chrome, you can select a specific element and look at what event listeners are attached to that specific element. Right-click on the element, select 'Inspect Element' or something similar, then scroll down in the right bar (I think it should contain applied styles, event listeners and how the 'box' is rendered with the width, height, margin, border and padding of the element).